# Excel cell from huge range (only showing few of them)

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've an excel file with some data validations. In one column only values from a range are allowed. The point is that this range has more than 4000 values and the dropdown doesnt show all of them. We need also, if possible, any kind of autofill for this. Happy to use VBA if necessary.

We have a bunch of streets and want the user to write in the cell one of them. If the user writes char 'A' cell should show only streets starting with letter 'A'

How can we show all the values? Is it possible to create the autofill for the range?

Comment: Is a drop-down with 4000 values seriously going to be useful,or do you need just the data validation part of this? And what should the 'autofill for the range' do, copy the whole range into a defined section?

Comment: Hi Spencer, thank you for your answer.

We have a bunch of streets and want the user to write in the cell one of them. If the user writes char 'A' cell should show only streets starting with letter 'A'

That's what I meant :)

Comment: Per [this article](https://www.contextures.com/xldataval08.html#:~:text=The%20list%20can%20show%20up%20to%20show%2032%2C767%20items%20from%20a%20list%20on%20the%20worksheet.) the dropdown should be able to cope with 4000 values. I don't know about the auto-filll, it's not a feature I've ever come across in excel myself but someone may be able to help.